# Update column with values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Merge_Pr': ['BKK_AOT', 'BKK_BFS', 'BKK_TG', 'HND_ANA'],
                    'UniqueName': ['PR1', 'PR2', 'PR3', 'PR18']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Merge_Pr': ['BKK_AOT','BKK_AOT','BKK_BFS','BKK_TG','BKK_TG','HND_ANA','HND_ANA'],
         'Quantity':[9240, 1433, 56779, 2230, 5560, 1004, 4553],
         'Requisition_Number': ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN',]})
```

I would like to update the column Requisition_Number (df2) with PR number from the column `UniqueName` in (df1) by key column `Merge_Pr`.

I tried with merge but it adds a new column to df2 but what I want is to have the result in the existing column `Requisition_Number` so the desired output would be:

```
    Merge_Pr    Quantity    Requisition_Number

0   BKK_AOT      9240         PR1
1   BKK_AOT      1433         PR1
2   BKK_BFS      56779        PR2
3   BKK_TG       2230         PR3
4   BKK_TG       5560         PR3
5   HND_ANA      1004         PR18
6   HND_ANA      4553         PR18
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

One solution: map `Merge_Pr` to a dictionary made from the two columns in df1.

```
df2.Requisition_Number = df2.Merge_Pr.map(dict(zip(df1.Merge_Pr, df1.UniqueName)))
```